# Glassfish 4.1.2 JVM failed to start exit code 127

Tags: java, jvm, glassfish-4

I'm working with glassfish4 server and now I'm facing problem when installing glassfish4 on server. I usually use `asadmin start-domain domain1` to start glassfish domain, and the error:

```
JVM failed to start: com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherException: The server exited prematurely with exit code 127.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Command start-domain failed.
```

It is glassfish-4.1.2 (clean instance with default domain1) and java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

And now I stuck here and need help to resolve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: exit code 127 usually means `command not found`. Do you have anything in your `server.log`?

Comment: @unwichtich no, there is only JMV args loading info and this error in server.log.

Comment: It was fixed with newest JDK 8u162 from Oracle (GF Readme said it need JDK 8u5+)

Comment: Then you should post this solution as an answer so the question can get marked as solved.

Comment: thanks, I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed with newest JDK 8u162 from Oracle (GF Readme said it need JDK 8u5+)